# Reference page and table of contents

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, pdftex

The last sentence of my last chapter ends on page 118. Just after the last line I used

```
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

to get the ‘References’ on page 119. This was fine. In ‘toc’ also, it shows that the ‘References’ is on page 119.
But when I click on ‘References’ in ‘toc’, it ended up on page 118 (I am using 'hyperef' package). How can I get this correctly. I also have a title page in my document (‘book’ class). The numbering starts from first page of ‘toc’ which is just after ‘titlepage’.

Comment: may be you need `\clearpage\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}`

Comment: However, it shows the entries of the 'References' but hide the heading 'References'. What I mean is when I click on some section, it ended up showing the name of the section followed by its contents which is not the case with 'References'. It shows only the contents of 'References'.

Comment: I want to accept your answer in your first comment. However, I don't see the option.

Comment: let us wait a moment if the question is not duplicated i will add an answer

Comment: @raj: You can't accept comments as answers. If there is no duplicate, touhami will add a 'real' answer which you could accept then.

Comment: @raj can you see my 2 last comments. especially update your `hyperref` package